# How can I check if two array contains the same value, even if they are in different indexes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm working on a personal project and I'm stump in the last part. I'm trying to only get the data for companies that have the same name of the companies in my database.

My goal at the end is to merge the two jsons obtained from the two following calls into one

```
    Call one: $http.get('//localhost:8081/api/jobs').then(function(res) 
    Call two: localhost:8081/api/glassdoor/
```

Full Code:

```
    $http.get('//localhost:8081/api/jobs').then(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res.data; //data from the database
    $scope.size = $scope.data.length; //length 132
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.size; i++) {
        if ($scope.data[i].glassdoor !== null && $scope.data[i].glassdoor !== undefined) {
            $scope.hasGlassdoor = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.size; i++) {
                if ($scope.data[i].glassdoor !== null && $scope.data[i].glassdoor !== undefined)
                    $scope.hasGlassdoor.push($scope.data[i]);
            }

            //Get the companies name that have glassdoor
            $scope.company = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.hasGlassdoor.length; j++) {
                $scope.company.push($scope.hasGlassdoor[j].company);
            }

            //Create the URL calls for my glassdoor api
            $scope.url = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < $scope.company.length; x++) {
                $scope.url.push('//localhost:8081/api/glassdoor/' + $scope.company[x]);
            }
            //For example : '//localhost:8081/api/glassdoor/A9.com'

            //Get the Glassdoor data
            var company = $scope.company;
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.url.length; j++) {
                $http.get($scope.url[j]).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.gData = response.data;
                    $scope.gSize = $scope.gData.length;
                    $scope.gName = [];

                    //Get the names of the companies that glassdoor returns
                    for(var x = 0; x < $scope.gSize; x++){
                         if ($scope.gData[x] !== null && $scope.gData[x] !== undefined) {
                            if ($scope.gData[x].name !== null && $scope.gData[x].name !== undefined) {
                                    $scope.gName.push($scope.gData[x].name);
                            }
                         }
                    }
                    //Now I'm trying to only get the names of the companies that are in my variable company
                    //For example '//localhost:8081/api/glassdoor/6sense
                    //returns data for 6sense, and a company named 6sense Technologies
                    //I'm trying to just get the data of 6sense

                    //
                    //      TODO
                    //


                    // My try using loDash returns undefined.
                    // I'm trying to see if $scope.gName is in var Company.
                    //if(_.includes(company, $scope.gName)){
                    //    gd.push($scope.gName);
                    //}

                }); //this is what is calling the glassdoor api
            }//end of the for loop for url.
        } //if statement to check for null
    } //first for loop
}).catch(function(error, res) {
    console.log("Error:", error, res);
});
```

Right now I'm working on small list so I can fix this issue.

My goal at the end is to have this as my finished json:

```
[  
   {  
      "company": "23andMe"
       "glassdoor":"https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-23andMe-EI_IE145899.11,18.htm"

"img":"https://www.23andme.com/static/img/icons/logo_alt.96cf7888b73d.svg"
       "international":null
       "link":"https://www.23andme.com/careers/"
       "location":"Mountain View, CA"
       "secondary":null
       "third":null
      "id":145899,
      "name":"23andMe",
      "website":"www.23andme.com",
      "isEEP":true,
      "exactMatch":true,
      "industry":"Biotech & Pharmaceuticals",
      "numberOfRatings":27,
      "squareLogo":"https://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/145899/23andme-squarelogo.png",
      "overallRating":"4.2",
      "ratingDescription":"Very Satisfied",
      "cultureAndValuesRating":"4.5",
      "seniorLeadershipRating":"3.6",
      "compensationAndBenefitsRating":"4.0",
      "careerOpportunitiesRating":"3.4",
      "workLifeBalanceRating":"4.3",
      "recommendToFriendRating":80,
      "sectorId":10005,
      "sectorName":"Biotech & Pharmaceuticals",
      "industryId":200021,
      "industryName":"Biotech & Pharmaceuticals",
      "featuredReview":{  
         "attributionURL":"https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Employee-Review-23andMe-RVW11447587.htm",
         "id":11447587,
         "currentJob":true,
         "reviewDateTime":"2016-08-03 15:05:20.157",
         "jobTitle":"Customer Care Reporesentative",
         "location":"Mountain View, CA",
         "jobTitleFromDb":"Customer Care Reporesentative",
         "headline":"Customer Care Representative",
         "pros":"the environment-everyone is extremely genuine, smart, and friendly. management is very understanding and open. Executives are transparent with everything going on in the company\r\nbenefits-free gym, food every day, snacks, great health coverage, rooftop access, etc\r\nworkspace-facilities does a phenomenal job at keeping everything extremely clean and fixes all issues ASAP. I don't feel like I'm sitting a boring desk job all day, it's a fun place to be",
         "cons":"Traffic through downtown mountain view can suck and the train can be kind of loud (I cannot think of a legitimate con, everything is awesome here)",
         "overall":5,
         "overallNumeric":5
      },
      "ceo":{  
         "name":"Anne Wojcicki",
         "title":"CEO",
         "numberOfRatings":15,
         "pctApprove":100,
         "pctDisapprove":0
      }
   }
]
```

Server.js that deals with the glassdoor call:

```
//Glassdoor api call
app.get('/api/glassdoor/:company', function(req, res, next) {
    var company = req.params.company;
    requestify.get('https://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=PRODUCT&t.k=KEY&userip=0.0.0.0&useragent=&format=json&v=1&action=employers&q=' + company).then(function(response) {
        // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
        gData = response.getBody();
        gData = gData.response.employers;
        res.json(gData);
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array, then enumerate it. If previous === current you have a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
app.get('/api/glassdoor/:company', function(req, res, next) {
    var company = req.params.company;
    requestify.get('https://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=PRODUCT&t.k=KEY&userip=0.0.0.0&useragent=&format=json&v=1&action=employers&q=' + company).then(function(response) {
        // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
        gData = response.getBody();
        gData = gData.response.employers;
        //What I added to only send the data of the companies that where like 'company'
        for (var i = 0; i < gData.length; i++) {
            if (gData[i].name === company) {
                gData = gData[i];
                res.send(gData);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Which doesn't answer the overall question but that is how I solved my particular issue.